# How to get common elements together in a python list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

This might sound like a stupid question but I have the following list:

```
list = ['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d']
```

And I want to get common elements together to rearrange it as:

```
sorted_list = ['a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d']
```

Is there any built in function in python to do that?

Comment: `sorted_list = sorted(list)`?

Comment: Common elements? Do you mean sorting?

Comment: @vaultah that's exactly what i wanted. Please post it as answer, i will mark correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Elisha512 no, your question is not entirely clear, and I'm not convinced that `sorted` is what you *actually* need.

Comment: you wanted to compare sorted list and list before sort ?

Comment: I think OP wants to group the common elements together from the list. sorted just gives the result. But it might not want OP wanted to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to get sorted list you could just use:

```
sorted_list = sorted(list)
```

which gives the output `['a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d']`

To sort and group elements by values:

```
list = sorted(list)
sorted_list = [[y for y in list if y==x] for x in list]
```

which gives the output `[['a','a'],['b','b'],['c','c'],['d','d']]`